# Explain the following syntax, i am not able to comprehend this

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

```
   int a=4;
   int *p=&a;
```

This syntax is right but when we write like this

```
   int a;
   int *p;
   *p=&a;
```

The third line is an error and i know that but, why is it possible to do so in first code

```
   int *p=&a;
```

We even do this when we pass the value by reference to functions ...
Thanks for the reply

Comment: initialization (`int *p=&a;`) and assignment (`*p=&a;`) are different things

Answer (score 4):

with `int *p=&a;`, you are

- declaring a variable (`p`) which is a pointer to an int
- assigning the address of `a` to `p`

An equivalent code would be

```
int *p; // declare a pointer variable 'p'
p = &a; // assign the address of a to 'p'
```

The third line `*p=&a;` is an error because `*p` denotes the (integer) value of the pointer whose address is `p`, the value is an `int` and not a `address of an int` (i.e., not a `pointer to an int`)

Comment: because `*p` denotes the (integer) value of the pointer whose address is `p`, the value is an `int` and not a `address of an int`

Answer (score 3):

The type is `int *`. So if the general pattern is:

```
T a;
T b;
a = b;
```

then with `T = int *`, the pattern is:

```
int * p;
p = &n;     // n is an int
```

The "`*`" in the *type specifier* `int *` should not be confused with the almost entirely unrelated *unary operator* that is also called "`*`".

Answer (score 1):

when you type

```
    int *p;
```

you are declaring the pointer p.
using the * again after it has been declared would de-reference the pointer.
so

```
    *p = &a;
```

would be saying "The value within pointer p = the reference to the value a"

the correct solution is

```
    int *p;
    p = &a
```